# How to retrieve HTML code from a website using GET (without Selenium etc)?

Tags: php, parsing, get, postman, wget

When making a GET request through PHP to https://comeback.pw/cats/146x?page=1, I receive a different HTML response, whereas everything works fine in a regular browser. What could be the issue?

It seems like there's JavaScript content protection in place. Is it possible to bypass it? When I copy a cURL request from Chrome and import it into Postman, it returns the CORRECT data. However, if I execute the same request in Postman again, I receive a different response. What might be causing this behavior?

Comment: Obviously, the content provider doesn't want scripts to scrap the content in any way... you should contact the provider and ask about legal way to access his content... and if he still doesn't want it, accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I test with a simple curl like this and it seems to be fine.

```
<?php

$url = "https://comeback.pw/cats/146x?page=1";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($response);

?>
```

Comment: Nope, It doesnt work for me.
I am getting like that
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=/ciez2a">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function md5cycle(e,t){var i=e[0],a=e[1],r=e[2],n=e[3];a=ii(a=ii(a=ii(a=ii(a=hh(a=hh(a=hh(a=hh(a=gg(a=gg(a=gg(a=gg(a=ff(a=ff(a=ff(a=ff(a,r=ff(r,n=ff(n,i=ff(i,a,r,n,t[0],7,-680876936),a,r,t[1],12,-389564586),i,a,t[2],17,606105819),n,i,t[3],22,-10445
25330),r=ff(r,n=ff(n,i=ff(i,a,r,n,t[4],7,-176418897),a,r,...`

Comment: It seems you are using localhost. You should use a standard host or server.

Answer (score 0):

> I receive a different HTML response, whereas everything works fine in
> a regular browser. What could be the issue?

That page has JavaScript which after execution does change content of said page. GNU `wget` does not support JavaScript execution. You need tool which does. I would suggest taking look at [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/) though I am not sure if it is not verboten as *etc* part of title of your question.